# How to find canvas object's position and click it with selenium (python)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, html5-canvas

Trying to make a selenium bot, but am unsure how to identify a canvas object's position and click them on this game. Here's what I have so far

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from time import sleep

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://w55.sfgame.net/")
canvas = driver.find_element("id", "canvas")
print(canvas.location)
print(canvas.size)
actionchain = ActionChains(driver)
actionchain.move_to_element(canvas)
actionchain.perform()
sleep(100)
driver.quit()
```